# Binomial determinants related to Hoggatt triangles

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, determinant

Let $d$ be a positive integer and let $0\leq{k}\leq{n}$ be non-negative integers.

Let $a_d(n)=\binom{n+d-1}{d}$ and $\binom{n}{k}_{d}=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1} \frac{a_d(n-j)}{a_d(k-j)}.$

(The matrix with entries $\binom{n}{k}_{d}$ is sometimes called Hoggatt triangle of order $d$. For $d=1$ it coincides with Pascal's triangle and for $d=2$ with the triangle of Narayana numbers).

Consider the matrix $A_d(n,k)$ whose $i,j-$ entry is $\binom{n-i+j+d-1}{n-1}$ for $0\leq {i,j}\leq{k-1}.$

Computer experiments suggest that
$$\det{A_d(n,k)}=\binom{n}{k}_{d}.$$
Any idea how to prove this? Is it possible to see directly from the matrix that the determinant satisfies $\binom{n}{k}_{d}=\binom{n}{n-k}_{d}?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Jacobi-Trudi identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_polynomial#Jacobi%E2%88%92Trudi_identities) give

$$s_{\lambda} = \det(h_{\lambda_i + j - i})_{i,j=1}^k$$

where $\lambda = (\lambda_1, \dots \lambda_k)$ is a partition with $k$ parts, $s_{\lambda}$ is a Schur function, and $h_i$ is a complete homogeneous symmetric function. If we work with $n$ variables and set them all equal to $1$ then

$$h_{\lambda_i + j - i}(\underbrace{1, 1, \dots 1}_{n \text{ times}}) = {\lambda_i + j - i + n - 1 \choose n - 1}$$

so comparing to the desired determinant we see that we want to set $\lambda_i = d$. (Note that it doesn't matter whether we index $i, j$ starting from $1$ or $0$ since only the difference between them matters anyway.) This gives that the desired determinant evaluation is

$$s_{d^k}(\underbrace{1, 1, \dots 1}_{n \text{ times}})$$

which is the number of [semistandard Young tableaux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau) with shape $d^k$ (a box with $d$ columns and $k$ rows) and entries in $\{ 1, \dots n \}$. These can be counted with the [semistandard hook length formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula#Semi-standard_tableaux_hook_length_formula), which gives

$$s_{d^k}(\underbrace{1, 1, \dots 1}_{n \text{ times}}) = \prod_{1 \le i \le k, 1 \le j \le d} \frac{n - i + j}{(k - i) + (d - j) + 1} = \prod_{1 \le i \le k} \frac{(n - i + 1)^{\overline{d}}}{(k - i + 1)^{\overline{d}}}$$

where $x^{\overline{d}}$ denotes the [rising factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) $x(x + 1) \dots (x + (d-1))$. Writing $a_d(n) = \frac{n^{\overline{d}}}{d!}$ and $\frac{a_d(n-j)}{a_d(k-j)} = \frac{(n-j)^{\overline{d}}}{(k-j)^{\overline{d}}}$, and reindexing the sum above by $1$, shows that this is equivalent to the desired result.

This argument might be slight overkill and one or more of the methods in Krattenthaler's *[Advanced Determinant Calculus](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9902004)* might be easier. It is maybe also worth saying that this argument can be rephrased using the [Lindstrom-Gessel-Viennot lemma](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/11/20/the-jacobi-trudi-identities/), since that lemma proves the Jacobi-Trudi identities and can be specialized to this case.

Comment: Thank you for this very informative answer!

Comment: @Johann: you're very welcome! I have no idea where these identities come from that you keep posting but I enjoy working on them.